# How to get data-ids array from div list where classes is active using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery 1.7.2 and div list with data-id in it, my goal is get id`s from divs where class is active. Question is how to prepare array with active ids using jquery? e.g myArray = [1,4].

```
<div id="district">
  <div class="item active" data-id="1">...</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="2">...</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="3">...</div>
  <div class="item active" data-id="4">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Follow steps: **1.** Loop over `.active` **2.** Get the value of `data-id` in the loop for current element **3.** Push the value in the array.  _Use these steps, when stuck ask question_

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I think maybe exist jquery method for do that.

Comment: Our friends [Google](https://www.google.com) and [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/) will help you.

Comment: Where is problem with this question? It is not clear?:D

Comment: It is clear, but it is showing **no efforts** to solve it. And when I hovered over downvote button it says _"This question does not show any research efforts;"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.map()` function of jquery to create the array

```
var arr = $("#district .item.active").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("id");
  }).get().join();
console.log(arr);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL2Bc/1363/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".item.active").each(function(value){
console.log(value); // try your code here
})
```